# What is the "Other Memory" in my HTC Windows 8S

Tags: 8.0, storage

I am using HTC Windows 8S, the device is good but the main problem is with the "Other Memory" in the Memory Section. The size of the Other Memory is exceeding day by day, I performed factory reset twice in order to fix the issue, but it doesn't seem to be very helpful. So plese help me to fix this issue on permanent basis.

Comment: The Make More Space app for HTC does NOTHING!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other Storage on Windows Phone 8 includes cached data that is stored on your device. Everything from email, games, videos, game info, app info, documents, images synced to SkyDrive are all items that can fill it up.

When you need to install an app or perform another action that requires more dedicated use of storage, this other space is supposed to relinquish it. Before GDR2, WP8 did a poor job with it. After GDR2, Microsoft started cleaning this up a little more aggressively.

Both [Nokia](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/storage-check/b4cf45cc-a355-40d2-8b74-51517a042a18) and [HTC](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=fc388ddb-433d-4c70-ac48-455175a2cbf5) have created apps to help you manually free some of this space up on your own.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Caschw
 for this valuable information, i hope HTC will make the things more easier.