# space occupied by other files in Storage Check in WP8

Tags: settings, storage

I'm using Lumia 620, WP8.
In the storage check option in Settings tab, i can able to see the spaces allocated by the files. 
Its listing the files in the order so as that last option is other. 
How can I view the files occupied by other?
How can i remove this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2311/106